# C Socket - captured packets have same ip_dst and ip_src

Tags: linux, packet-capture

I'm using C SOCK_RAW socket to capture incoming packets on my machine (192.168.0.16), when trying to display some fields of the IP packet captured, everything is correct (TTLs, length, etc...), except that my ip_dst and ip_src are... the same ! (in fact the ip_dst seems to have been overwritten at some point...

The structure of the code used:

```
sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP))

recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, IP_MAXPACKET, 0, &from, &fromlen)

...
struct ip iphdr; //and then copying the right section of "buffer" into it...

printf("Source: %s - Dest: %s \n",inet_ntoa(iphdr.ip_src),inet_ntoa(iphdr.ip_dst));
```

Displays:

```
Source: 192.168.0.5 - Dest: 192.168.0.5
```

while i can see (from Wireshark) that the real destination is 192.168.0.16 (which is indeed a VM running on 192.168.0.5 - in case that could explain this weird phenomenenon).

Thanks for helping me to understand this !

EDIT: this (listening) program is running on the VM (192.168.0.16)

Comment: Where is the C socket program running? On .16? or on the VM host .5?

Comment: Hi - it's running inside the VM (192.168.0.16)

Answer (score 0):

according to the `inet_ntoa` manual:

> The inet_ntoa() function converts the Internet host address in, given in network byte order, to a string in IPv4  dotted-decimal  notation.
>          The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite.

Which means every time you call this function, the results will be overwritten to the same address. so to keep the result somewhere else, you need to copy it into some buffer using something like `strcpy`.

```
char src[15], dst[15];
strcpy(src, inet_ntoa(iphdr.ip_src));
strcpy(dst, inet_ntoa(iphdr.ip_dst));
printf("Source: %s - Dest: %s \n", src, dst);
```

Note: this answer is solely for the those who comes here through a search result since this post is really old.